# How to make an activity popup with timer

Tags: java, android, timer, popup

Hello guys how are you today I hope you are OK
I have an application with many activity's :

- Main-activity
- activity1
- activity2
- activity3

what I need to do is make the activity3 popup every (x) minute, for example, every 2 or 3 minutes the activity3 popup how can I do that and thanks in advance.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //load the xml file for the starting loading screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("MainActivity:", "onCreate: created activity_main.xml UI succesfully.");

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimaryActivity.class));
            finish();

            Log.d("MainActivity:", "onCreate: waiting 5 seconds for MainActivity... loading PrimaryActivity.class");
        }
    }, 5000 );
}
```

}

I didn't know how to try this before posting so I need your help thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it's possible at the moment, you shouldn't do it. As Android grows, Google adds a lot of restrictions to the OS to make it better. Since Android Q, Google wants activities to be started as a result of user interaction https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts .What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

'Make the popup function static and call it with class name like'

yourclassname.popupFunction(Context);

'in on create method where you want to open the primary activity'

```
public static void popupFunction(Activity activity){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              startActivity(new Intent(activity, PrimaryActivity.class));
              finish();

              Log.d("MainActivity:", "onCreate: waiting 5 seconds for MainActivity... 
                     loading PrimaryActivity.class");


            }
        },5000);
    }
```

'Hope you get the answer Thanks'